# Machine Keys Settings in IIS 10

Tags: signalr, iis-10, machinekey

I am using windows2016 - IIS 10 server and trying to generate the machine keys which are required for my application. The problem here is "Generate a unique key for each application"
the setting is disappeared in IIS 10 whereas same is available in IIS 7.5

Anyone know how to enable "Generate a unique key for each application" in IIS 10

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, we have "IsolateByAppId" and "IsolateApps" setting for the auto generate to replace the "Generate a unique key for each application" in IIS 10.

> If you add the "IsolateApps" modifier to the "AutoGenerate" ValidationKey value, ASP.NET generates a unique encrypted key for each application by using each application's AppDomainAppVirtualPath. This is the default setting.
>
> If you add the "IsolateByAppId" modifier to the "AutoGenerate" ValidationKey value, ASP.NET generates a unique encrypted key for each application by using each application's AppDomainAppId. If two distinct applications share a virtual path (perhaps because those applications are running on different ports), this flag can be used to further distinguish them from one another. The "IsolateByAppId" flag is understood only by ASP.NET 4.5, but it can be used regardless of the MachineKeySection.CompatibilityMode setting.